# Is there a geometric interpretation for the characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Linear algebra has a lot of nice geometric interpretations which makes understanding intuitive. Is there also one regarding the characteristic polynomial and why its zero-points are the eigenvalues?

Comment: Do you understand the geometry of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: I understand that the eigenvectors only get scaled by the transformation and the eigenvalues is the amount the eigenvectors are being scaled by

Comment: From the definition it follows that $A-\lambda I$ is singular for an eigenvalue $\lambda$. The determinant measures how close to singularity we are, which is what is expressed in the characteristic polynomial.